# Hit undefined is not an object (this.state.text) when creating searchable flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a search bar to filter data for flatlist. In the code below, I have created a list of name and pass the name list into flatlist. Then, I would like to pass in the input from search bar to 
searchFilterFunction to filter the data. The issue is when I enter the page, I have encountered error "Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.text). Would like to know the cause and solution for this case.

```
const DATA = [
    {
        name: 'Name 1',
    }, {
        name: 'Name 2',
    }, {
        name: 'Name 3',
    }, {
        name: 'Name 4',
    }, {
        name: 'Name 5',
    }, 
];


export default class NameListView extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          loading: false,
          text: '',
        };

        this.searchFilterFunction = this.searchFilterFunction.bind(this);
    }

    searchFilterFunction (text) {
        const newData = DATA.filter(function(item) {
          const itemData = `${item.name}`;
          const textData = text;

          return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });

        this.setState({
           text: newData
        });
    };

    renderSeparator(){
        return <View style={styles.separator}/>
    }

    renderHeader() {
        return (
          <SearchBar
            placeholder="Choose Recipient"
            lightTheme
            round
            onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <View>
                    <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
                        data={DATA}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>
                            <ListItem
                                title={item.name}
                                chevron={{color : 'black'}}
                                leftIcon={<FontAwesome name={'user-circle'} size={25} color= 
 {'#E3E3E3'}/>}   
                            />
                        }
                        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
                    />
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing `this` inside `renderHeader` it needs to either be bound or called with the correct scope.

You can change the call to something like:

```
ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader.bind(this)}
```

Or something like:

```
ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
```